# Comparing two dates minutes in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is comparing a DateTime variable and a date inside a table in sql server if the the differece between those two date are less than 30 min the select query will return some values I'm using c# to send the DateTime variable

```
string query = "Select * from LoginAttempts where IP_ADDRESS='" + Ipadress + "' and ATTEMPTS<"+MaxLoginAttempts+" and (GETDATE()-LOGIN_DATE)<30";
```

`and (GETDATE()-LOGIN_DATE)<30` I know this is a wrong statement but how should I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, stop building your SQL dynamically like that. Use parameterized SQL instead.

Next, I think you just want [`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx). If you know that `LOGIN_DATE` will always be in the past, you just need to add 30 minutes to that, and check that the result is later than `GETDATE()` - or equivalently, subtract 30 minutes from now and check that `LOGIN_DATE` is later than the result:

```
string query = @"Select * from LoginAttempts where IP_ADDRESS=@IPAddress'
                 and ATTEMPTS < @MaxLoginAttempts
                 and LOGIN_DATE > DATEADD(minute, -30, GETDATE())";
// Then fill in the parameters in the SqlCommand
```

As noted in comments, applying `DATEADD` to `GETDATE()` instead of to `LOGIN_DATE` allows more optimization, because it only needs to be performed once instead of once for each row, and allows any index on `LOGIN_DATE` to be effective.

You can use [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) instead in this case, but it's worth being aware that `DATEDIFF` doesn't always do exactly what you *might* expect it to, as it's about "boundary crossings". Not much of an issue here, but it means that the difference between (say) September 1st and August 31st is 1 month, as is the difference between September 30th and August 1st.

In this case the impact would just be that (say) 10:00:59 and 10:30:00 would be seen as 30 minutes, despite them only being *just* over 29 minutes apart... whereas the difference between 10:00:00 and 10:29:59 would also be 29 minutes despite being very nearly 30 minutes apart. So you'd be slightly inconsistent in terms of real elapsed time.

Comment: Although I agree with the remarks, I do cringe a bit at seeing `and DATEADD(minute, 30, LOGIN_DATE) > GETDATE();`. One should always apply the function to the constant and leave the field alone so the query processor can use the statistics, or even better, the index (if present) related to the field. In this case you'd have to reverse the construction to `and LOGIN_DATE > DATEADD(minute, -30, GETDATE());`

Comment: @deroby: Yes, that makes sense, and is a very good point - I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), LOGIN_DATE)
```

So the whole query would look like this:

```
string query = "Select * from LoginAttempts where IP_ADDRESS='" + Ipadress + "' 
and ATTEMPTS<"+MaxLoginAttempts+" and DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), LOGIN_DATE)<30";
```

Comment: Note that that can give some odd results - see the final paragraph of my answer for an example.

Comment: Same remark as to Jon Skeet. A construction like `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), LOGIN_DATE)<30` will force a scan over the data instead of being able to use the indexes efficiently =(